# Unable to include GLFW/glfw.h on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I am setting up Visual Studio for C++ OpenGL. I tried following a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR4fNpBjmq8) but it still keep on getting this error: "cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h"

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
}

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

It is exact same as the demo on the official GLFW website but it does not work. Any way to fix this?

Comment: ***it still keep on getting this error: "cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h"** That means the folder containing GLFW is not in your compiler's search path for include directories.

Comment: ***Any way to fix this?*** Fix the path you entered in the "Additional Include Directories" setting for the configuration you are testing

Comment: Please include the path as the tutorial like `C:\xxxxx\glfw-3.3.1.bin.WIN32\include` into `Additional Include Directories`(right-click on your  project-->C++-->General-->Additional Include directories) and then reopen your project. Besides, please add the path of the `glfw3.lib` for the ` additional dependencies` like `C:\xxx\glfw-3.3.1.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2019\glfw3.lib` and also add 'opengl32.lib'(right-click on your  project-->Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is exact same as the demo on the official GLFW website but it does
>   not work. Any way to fix this?

Thanks for your sharing the tutorial with me and l have followed this guidance and this works in my side and builds without any errors. So please follow my steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** add the path of `glfw3.h` into **Additional Include Directories**(Right-click on your project-->`Configuration Properties`-->`C/C++`-->`General`-->`Additional Include Directories`).

[image]

**2)** add `glfw3.lib` into **Additional Dependencies**(Right-click on the project-->`Configuration Properties`-->`Linker`-->`Input`-->`Additional Dependencies`) and do not forget to add `opengl32.lib`  into it

[image]

**3)** close,reopen VS and then you will rebuild your project without any errors.

**In addition**, if you want to enter into `glfw3.h` file to see its function when you debug it, you should add the path into **Library Directories**(Right-click on the project-->`Configuration Properties`-->`VC++ Directories`-->`Library Directories`).

[image]

Hope it could help you.