# Unable to link 'GLFW' in Visual Studio in #include<GLFW/glwf3.h>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I am trying to include
`#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>`
to create a window in OpenGL, but am getting this error, `Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h"  OpenGL  E:\OpenGL\src\Application.cpp   1`

- [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g73Oj.png)
- [Included Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43jIC.png)

I have tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709868/unable-to-include-glfw-glfw-h-on-visual-studio-2019) solution, but am still getting this same issue.

Comment: Where is the `GLFW` directory located? You need to edit your project settings for the preprocessor to find it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes I have added the linker and header directories in project settings.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709868/unable-to-include-glfw-glfw-h-on-visual-studio-2019) solution but was not successful

Comment: What is the *exact* header-file directory that you have added? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am sorry, I am new to asking questions on Stackoverflow. I have added the directory locations in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should check whether you are building a x86 project?

[image]

You need to make sure that you add the configuration properties to the correct build target and platform for your code.

And I suggest you could select "All Platforms" for the platform and select "All Configurations" for the Configuration when changing the properties.

[image]

Comment: @Kanit Mann Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.